# jQuery hide rows from table

Tags: jquery, html

I am new using jQuery, and I am trying to hide rows from a table like that:

```
<table border="1" width="100%" id="table1">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center">
            First Row   
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center">
            Second row  
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center">
            Thrid row   
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to hide the first and the 3erd row from table, how can I do it? I am trying but I cannot achieve my goal with this code:

```
$('#table1 tr').hide()
```

Comment: `$('#table1 tr:first(), #table1 tr:eq(2)').hide()`, or ` #table1 tr:last()` if it's always going to be the last row.

Comment: What is the expected and actual behavior of the code you provide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are numerous ways to do this. Here's one:

```
$("#table1 tr:even").hide();
```

Noting that row indexes are zero-based, so the first and third rows are "even". Of course this hides *all* even rows but your example only has three rows.

To explicitly target individual rows by (zero-based) index:

```
var $rows = $("#table1 tr");
$rows.eq(0).hide();
$rows.eq(2).hide();
```

Or, if you have control over the html you can add a class to whichever rows you want to hide and select based on the class.